Two Tail Hypothesis testing on a Normalised Binomial Distribution
I have come across a problem whilst solving this problem in my textbook:

It is claimed that the proportion of people worldwide with mixed handedness is 1%. Amie thinks this proportion is incorrect. She interviews 600 people, and finds that 11 of them are mixed handed. Test the claim at the 4% significance level.

I have found that I get different solutions depending on the side I test from as a result of doing a continuity correction when I approximate this binomial distribution with a normal one.
$X\sim B(600,0.01)$ approximates to $X\sim N(6,5.94)$
Now Amie finds that 11 of them are mixed handed. So testing this I can either check the probability
$P(X\geq11)\rightarrow P(X>10.5)$ is greater than 0.98
$P(X\leq11)\rightarrow P(X<11.5)$ is less than 0.02
The two tail proportions must be less than 2% in order to reject the null hypothesis. However applying a continuity correction on the two respectively, I get different Z values and different probailities, one probability telling me to reject the null hypothesis and the other to accept it at the 4% significance level.
I am confused why depending on which side you test on, you get a different answer. This shouldn't be correct. The answers use continuity corrections but it seems that by doing these corrections you run into this problem.

Since the problem doesn't state whether Amie thinks the $1\%$ figure is too high, or too low, the most natural interpretation of the hypothesis to be tested is
$$H_0 : \theta = 0.01 \quad \text{vs.} \quad H_a : \theta \ne 0.01,$$
where $\theta$ is the true proportion of people worldwide with mixed handedness.
For a sample size of $n = 600$, the exact test statistic is $$X \mid H_0 \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n = 600, \theta = 0.01).$$  Again, since we are not given a particular Type I error allocation for each tail, we assume that the $\alpha = 0.04$ significance level for the test will be equally split.  So we have a lower critical value $x_L$ and an upper critical value $x_U$, such that $$\Pr[X \le x_L \mid H_0] \le 0.02, \quad \Pr[X \ge x_U \mid H_0] \le 0.02,$$ and if we observe either $X \le x_L$ or $X \ge x_U$, we reject $H_0$ in favor of $H_a$ at the $\alpha = 0.04$ level.
We compute the binomial CDF and summarize the results in the following table, stopping when the cumulative probability exceeds $\alpha/2 = 0.02$:
$$\begin{array}{c|c}
x & \Pr[X \le x \mid H_0] \\
\hline
0 & 0.00240501 \\
\color{red}{1} & \color{red}{0.0169808} \\
2 & 0.0610763
\end{array}$$
and similarly, we calculate for the upper tail, noting that $x$-values above $n\theta + 3\sqrt{n\theta(1-\theta)} \approx 13.3$ will have probabilities roughly in the range of $1 - \Phi(3) \approx  10^{-3} < 0.02$:
$$\begin{array}{c|c}
x & \Pr[X \ge x \mid H_0] \\
\hline
13 & 0.00849164 \\
\color{red}{12} & \color{red}{0.0195297} \\
11 & 0.0417932
\end{array}$$
Thus, the lower and upper critical values for the exact test are $x_L = 1$ and $x_U = 12$.  Since the observed value is $X = 11$, the conclusion is that the data do not furnish sufficient evidence at the $4\%$ significance level to reject the hypothesis that the true proportion of people worldwide with mixed handedness is not $1\%$.
The exact test statistic we are using is based on the binomial distribution; it is not a $z$-test based on a normal approximation (with or without continuity correction).  It is worth noting that, due to the discrete valued nature of the test statistic, it is not possible to allocate the entire $\alpha = 0.04$ to the test.  But even so, the smallest alpha for which a two-sided test would reject the null hypothesis would be $0.0417932 \times 2 \approx 0.0835863$, or about $8.36\%$.  Another way to think about it is that the two-sided $p$-value of the result $X = 11$ is
$$\Pr[X \ge 11 \mid H_0] + \Pr[X \le 1 \mid H_0] = 0.0417932 + 0.0169808 \approx 0.058774,$$ where we have used the rule to add up all outcomes of $X$ that are not more likely than the outcome that was observed.  This completes our discussion about how to perform the computation using an exact test statistic.

To perform the computation using a $z$-test, which in my opinion is not recommended due to the null mean being only $n\theta = 6$ (hence the binomial distribution is heavily skewed even for such a sample size), we employ the test statistic
$$Z \mid H_0 = \frac{\hat \theta - \theta}{\sqrt{\hat \theta(1 - \hat \theta)/n}} \sim \operatorname{Normal}(0,1),$$
where $\hat \theta = X/n$, the sample proportion.  For $X = 11$,
$$Z = \frac{11/600 - 0.01}{\sqrt{\frac{11}{600}(1 - \frac{11}{600})/600}} \approx 1.52157.$$
Then we reject $H_0$ at the $\alpha = 0.04$ level if $Z > z_{\alpha/2}^*$, where $z_{\alpha/2}^*$ is the upper $\alpha/2$ percentile of the standard normal distribution, in this case $$z_{\alpha/2}^* = z_{0.02}^* = \Phi^{-1}(1 - 0.02) \approx 2.05375.$$  Since $1.52157 < 2.05375$, we fail to reject $H_0$ at the $4\%$ level (no continuity correction).
Note that this $z$-test is more conservative than the test that uses the standard error under the null hypothesis.  We could have chosen the statistic
$$Z_0 \mid H_0 = \frac{\hat \theta - \theta}{\sqrt{\theta (1 - \theta)/n}},$$
where the difference is that the denominator uses $\theta = 0.01$ instead of $\hat \theta = 11/600$.  In such a case, we would have
$$Z_0 = \frac{11/600 - 0.01}{0.01(0.99)/600} \approx 2.05152,$$
which is just shy of the critical value $z_{0.02}^* = 2.05375$, and again, we fail to reject $H_0$.

Finally, there seems to be some confusion about how to apply continuity correction to a $z$-test.  In the above example, I did not use it, to show how the test would be done in a simple setting.  However, if you want to use it, then we would go back to the binomial distribution of $X$ and observe
$$X \mid H_0 \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n = 600, \theta = 0.01)$$
is approximated by
$$X' \mid H_0 \sim \operatorname{Normal}(\mu = n\theta = 6, \sigma^2 = n\theta(1-\theta) = 5.94),$$
as you have pointed out.  We observed $X = 11$ and we want to compute the $p$-value
$$p = \Pr[X \ge 11] \overset{\text{c.c.}}{\approx} \Pr[X' \ge 10.5] = \Pr\left[\frac{X' - \mu}{\sigma} \ge \frac{10.5 - 6}{\sqrt{5.94}}\right] = \Pr[Z \ge 1.84637] = 0.0324191 > 0.02.$$
Thus we fail to reject $H_0$; the test statistic is $Z = 1.84637 < z_{0.02}^* = 2.05375$.
